# Java Rest API - resource/data separation with JPA

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

i'm currently building a rest-api with Java-EE/Jax-RS/JPA.
I already have a working database + database model and used the eclipse option for creating jpa-entities from existing tables.
I've created some basic services and i'm curious now whether the use of jpa-associations makes sense for building a rest-api or not because it sometimes leads to a big chunk of data getting exposed. I'm also unsure about where to separate the data that is being exposed.

E.g:

```
table "FOLDER" has an id, name
table "FOLDER_ITEM" has an id, folder_id (fk), item_id (fk)
table "ITEM" has an id, name, itemprop_id(fk)
table "ITEM_PROP" has an id, valueA, valueB, valueC
```

Calling **/folders/1** currently outputs:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Folder1",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "pencil",
      "item_prop": {
        "id": "1",
        "valueA": "example",
        "valueB": "example",
        "valueC": "example"
      }
    },...]
}
```

which adds up to a lot of data if there are a lot of items connected to a folder.

So i thought it maybe simpler and cleaner to separate the data by creating a service **/items/{id}** which would give me only one item at a time.
But in this case i would also have to create a service for getting the items of a folder. E.g **/items/?withFolderId=1**
or even **/folders/1/items**. I see the following options:

1) use jpa-associations but mark the list of items (inside the folder-class) as json-ignored for **/folders/1** and force the output of the items when calling **/folders/1/items**.

2) write queries on my own

in case of the latter i'm asking my self "why would i even use jpa at all?"

While beeing confused by this i might also have to say that all my tables have a foreign key to a user-id.
So i usually only want to get the folders of a specific user (the user who is currently logged in) by creating a service **/users/1/folders** and at this point where would i separate the data ?
I could serve my entire client from the **/users/** endpoint which would lead to the same problem as above. And now we can definitely talk about a big chunk of data getting exposed, depending on how much folders a user has and how much items the folders contain.

```
{
  "id":1
  "name":"testuser"
  "password":"PW"
  "folders":
    [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Folder1",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "pencil",
          "item_prop": {
            "id": "1",
            "valueA": "example",
            "valueB": "example",
            "valueC": "example"
          }
        },....]
    },....]
}
```

I feel like i'm distracting myself a lot with this problem. Are there any suggestions or common ways to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jackson library then you can mention **@JsonIgnore** to avoid json response. Following Example code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="address")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"id","companies","clientDetails"})
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = {"companies","clientDetails"})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Address implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="address_line1")
private String addressLine1;

@Column(name="address_line2")
private String addressLine2;

@Column
private String city;

@Column
private String country;

@Column(name="phone_no")
private String phoneNo;

@Column(name="postal_code")
private String postalCode;

@Column
private String state;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to ClientDetail
@OneToMany(mappedBy="addressBean",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<ClientDetail> clientDetails;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Company
@OneToMany(mappedBy="address", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Company> companies;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out :) I just figured this out on my own in the last few hours. The only question left is where to separate the data but i guess that differs from application to application.